# Invalid zip file format - Magisk 22.1

Tags: twrp, magisk

I have OnePlus 5t, Twrp 3.5.2_9-0-cheeseburger_dumpling, and when I'm trying to flash the magisk zip it's tell me: `Invalid zip file format`.

I searched google and found that I need the least TWRP version, but I have the least version... What can I do?

Edit:

In V22.1 (least) the only zip file is called "Source code (zip)", and in the TWRP its says `Invalid zip file format`. Same in V22.0. The next version available is 21.4, in V21.4 the link name is not "Source code (zip)", the link name is: "Magisk-v21.4.zip", and in the TWRP it's working well and flash into the system! Why it is like that? And what I don't understand?

Link to all versions: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases

Comment: Ty Robert!!!

In V22.1 (least) the only zip file is called "Source code (zip)", and in the TWRP its says `Invalid zip file format`. Same in V22.0. The next version available is 21.4, in V21.4 the link name is not "Source code (zip)", the link name is: "Magisk-v21.4.zip", and in the TWRP it's working well and flash into the system! Why it is like that? And what I don't understand?

Link to all versions: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases

Comment: LOL... so the real least version is V21.4?

Comment: read the install instructions. download apk and rename to zip

Comment: I didn't notice... ty!

Comment: yeah that's new since v22.0 now all inofficial tutorials  are outdated. most people did not even notice that custom recovery flashable zip is no longer official recommended install method and only exist for legacy support :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have downloaded the "Source code" release of Magisk which is for developers you want to build/compile Magisk on their own or make modifications to the code.

If you want to install Magisk from within a custom recovery ROM such as TWRP since Magisk v22.0 you have download the "APK" release which is at the same time a ZIP file with can be installed via recovery:

> In some custom recoveries, the installation may fail silently (it
> might look like success but in reality it bootloops). This is because
> the installer scripts cannot properly detect the correct device info
> or the recovery environment does not meet its expectation. If you face
> any issues, use the Patch Image method as it is guaranteed to work
> 100% of the time. Due to this reason, installing Magisk through custom
> recoveries on modern devices is no longer recommended. The custom
> recovery installation method exists purely for legacy support.
>
> - Download the Magisk APK
> - Rename the .apk file extension to .zip, for
>   example: Magisk-v22.0.apk → Magisk-v22.0.zip. If you have trouble
>   renaming the file extension (like on Windows), use a file manager on
>   Android or the one included in TWRP to rename the file.
> - Flash the zip
>   just like any other ordinary flashable zip.
> - Warning: sepolicy.rule
>   file of modules may be stored in cache partition, do not clear it.
> - Check whether the Magisk app is installed. If it isn’t installed
>   automatically, manually install the APK.

https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#custom-recovery